# Test Error: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testing.users' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing

I make this simple test:

```
public function test_my_awesome_test()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/awesome/test');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

But after run test it's display me error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'testing.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where
> `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

I had this same error if I needed to print some data from database. This tables exist and website works correctly. Who know where is problem?

Comment: Check the phpunit.xml file in the laravel directory. Below attributes should be in comment line. If it is not, turn them into comment lines.
`<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/><server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>`

Comment: I don't have this line and I try to add that but it doesn't work. I use Docker (sail) if it's important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#running-tests), Sail overrides the DB name you defined in the `.env` file when you run the tests. You need to remove the following line from your `phpunit.xml` file:

```xml
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="testing"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

make .testing file in root of project and set database connection config like .env file in that . if you run a test , laravel use .testing instead of .env to read enviroment

Comment: What if different. I can use this same db like n my project.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel Sail creates a dedicated database named ***testing*** so that your tests are isolated from your main database and therefore don't interfere with the data within it (source: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sail#running-tests). Sail also modifies the **phpunit.xml** file in your project to point at this ***testing*** database when running tests, by adding this line of code...

```
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="testing"/>
```

The error message you reported stated `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testing.users' doesn't exist`.

If you examine the ***testing*** database (e.g. using MySQL Workbench) you will see that it is an empty database and this is consistent with the error message you receive i.e. no `users` table exists within the ***testing*** database. The fact that you have a `users` table in your main database is irrelevant as your test is not set to look at your main database.

One solution (already given) is to remove the above line of code from your **phpunit.xml** file. However, I would NOT recommend this approach as your tests will pollute your main database and may inadvertently delete data you wanted to keep.

Clearly, if the ***testing*** database is empty, then migrations need to be run to create the appropriate tables prior to the test running. Helpfully, PHPUnit provides a `RefreshDatabase` trait which, when utilised, will call `php artisan migrate:fresh` on your ***testing*** database if migrations haven't already been run.

The *best solution*, therefore, is to use this `RefreshDatabase` trait in your test cases, as described in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test):

```
<?php
 
namespace Tests\Feature;
 
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;
 
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
 
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     */
    public function test_basic_example(): void
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');
 
        // ...
    }
}
```